# NGUI listing during a runtime with sprites

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have following idea, I want to make NGUI listing of my objects, but I want it to happen only during a runtime by pressing some code, however I am not sure how to achieve it, because objects enter a game free on their own, and I am not quite sure how to present them in a listing with sprites? Any solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding how to make a list of things with NGUI, there are plenty of example code for doing that which comes with the NGUI package, check out NGUI -> Examples -> Scenes. the examples that may be relevant is 7, 8 and 9

If you want to display all objects you either want to keep track of the all the time by making them register them selfs at the object that is going to display them, when they are created

Or you can find all objects of a type with [FindObjectsOfType](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) at the time of displaying